# Multilayered Perceptron Code Explanation

Tags: matlab, neural-network, octave, perceptron

[image]

**Solution:**

Generate Training Set

```
traincol1 = linspace(0.1, 15, 40)';
eps = (0.2*rand(40,1)) - 0.1;
traincol2 = sin(traincol1)./traincol1 - eps;
train = [traincol1 traincol2];
save('snn_a.txt','train');
save('snn_a.mat','train');
```

Generate Test Set

```
testcol1 = linspace(0.1, 15, 400)';
eps = (0.2*rand(400,1)) - 0.1;
testcol2 = sin(testcol1)./testcol1 - eps;
test = [testcol1 testcol2];
save('snn_b.txt','test');
save('snn_b.mat','test');
```

Training the Neural Network

```
function net = train_net(trainingset, hidden_neurons)    
% Parameters:     
% train_set:      
% labels - y     
% hidden_neurons_count:      
% Return value:     
% net – object representing a neural network    
% initialization     
% hidden neuron activation function- tanh,     
% output neuron activation - linear     

net=newff(trainingset(:, 1)', trainingset(:, 2)',hidden_neurons,
{'tansig', 'purelin'},'trainlm'); 
rand('state',sum(100*clock));      %random numbers generator initialization     
net=init(net);                     %weights initialization     
net.trainParam.goal = 0.01;        %stop- mse criterion     
net.trainParam.epochs = 400;       %number of epochs iterations     
net=train(net,trainingset(:, 1)', trainingset(:, 2)'); %network training
```

Main Program

```
% input data area
load('snn_a.mat');
load('snn_b.mat');
hidden_neurons = 4;
% net training
net = train_net(train, hidden_neurons);
% assigning results
resulttrain = net(train(:, 1)')';
resulttest = net(test(:, 1)')';
% drawing
hold on
sn = @(x) sin(x) / x;
fplot(sn, [0, 15],'g');
plot(train(:, 1), resulttrain, 'r');
legend('Original function', ' Result')
hold off
% print mse results
mse(net, train(:, 2)', resulttrain')
mse(net, test(:, 2)', resulttest')
```

**Can you explain train_net() and the Main Program?**

Is there any way I can improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much to explain.

train_net basically uses the function `newff` to create a Feed-Forward Backpropagation network with the given parameters (number of hidden neurons, num of epochs, error goal...) and it uses your training dataset to train the neuron (adjust the weights of the neurons).

Then your main program uses the trained neural network to get the predictions for both the train set and the test set.

It finally plots the Perfect expected result with the results of the train and test sets, to visualize how good the network is performing.

And finally it's calculating the mse for some numerical analysis of the performance.

Comment: Is there any hidden bug? Do you see anything to improve?

Comment: I dont' see any bug. Improving what? You specify the maximum error allowed in `net.trainParam.goal`. If you want better results reduce this number and increase epochs. If it doesn't reach the desired goal try increasing the number of neurons. But you are trying to learn a `sinc` which is a difficult function, and neural nets are not "magic". It might be that you cannot go below a certain error level.

Comment: I don't see any `sinc` in the code. Can u plz clarify?

Comment: `sin(x) / x` is called a `sinc` function. It's very used in engineering.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function

Comment: What is your alternative suggestion?

Comment: I think if your school homework tells you to use a `sinc` function you don't have much alternatives. I just pointed that it's a difficult function. But if you didn't know it how did you manage to do the trick of starting `traincol1` at 0.1 instead of 0 to avoid a 0/0 indeterminate form? Is this really your code? Or you are just blindly executing code?

Comment: This is not my homework. This is not my code. I have collected some code and trying to understand for my self study.